# Angular acceleration in rigid body dynamics

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm a little confused. In rigid body dynamics, could we write $\alpha = \frac{a}{r}$ everywhere in combined translational and rotational motion? If not, then where we could write it?

Answer (score 2):

The equation $$\alpha = \frac{a}{r}$$ only applies to a point moving in a circle about a fixed axis. In this case, $a$ represents the acceleration due to the rotation only, and is in the tangential direction. This is because the linear distance traveled by that point on the object is the same as the arc length rotated multiplied by the radius, meaning that $$\theta = \frac{s}{r}$$ So, taking the second time derivative, the original equation is produced. However, this only applies when the axis itself is not moving. In general, this is not true as the acceleration of the axis must be accounted for as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP is asking about rolling necessarily.  I think they are just asking about a general angular acceleration and translational acceleration. Although, what you do have here is correct about rolling without slipping.

Comment: It depends on what $a$ represents. Is $a$ the linear acceleration of the COM, or is it the linear acceleration of a point on the body a distance $r$ away from the axis of rotation? I would say the latter is more general. Your answer relates the former to a point on the outside of a rolling, circular object.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens: You do have a point; my answer wasn't generalized enough.

Comment: I believe you are on the right track though. Nothing a good edit can't fix :)